# Turning Probe "Off/On" using SOMA command through SOAPUI

Tags: xslt, soap, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, ibm-datapower

Can anyone help me with SOMA command/message to turn off/on the probe in datapower.

Thanks & Regards,
Sreevathsa A

Comment: I know I've done it but don't have access to my code now. Check for `debug-mode` in the docs I think will lead you to the probe

Comment: @Stefan, thanls for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use below SOAP message

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soapenv:Body>


<dp:request xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management" domain="hubowner">
 <dp:modify-config>
    <XMLFirewallService name="Test">
        <DebugMode>off</DebugMode>
    </XMLFirewallService>
 </dp:modify-config>


  </dp:request>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```